# How do I get the group members count number fast from ABAddressBook

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

Is there a way to get the group members count from the ABAddressBook without looping through all group members?

I used ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers to get the array count for all group, It is so much for the pain as for performance.

**Is there another way to get this count? such as use sql sentence query the ABAddressBook directly.**

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
                CFArrayRef members = ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers(currentGroup);
                CFIndex memberCount = CFArrayGetCount(members);
```